# Huge number of strange entries reported by SysInternals' autoruns on my Win7 Ultimate pc

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, sysinternals

I have been searching for an answer to this for about a month, but without success: A Huge number of strange entries are reported by SysInternals' autoruns utility when I run it on my Windows 7 Ultimate machine. These entries do not exist on my work PC, nor on my virtual PC (both Win7).

All I could figure out is that most of these entries (99%) point to Microsoft DLLs. I tried installing several applications under my virtual PC, but these entries were not created. So, how did they end up in my registry? Could it be from malware?

Here's a list of some of the groups and a screenshot of several entries from the first group:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GpExtensions
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Protocols\Filter
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Protocols\Handler
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellServiceObjects
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellServiceObjects
HKLM\Software\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\Software\Classes\Drive\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
.......
HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
.......
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\NameSpace_Catalog5\Catalog_Entries
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\NameSpace_Catalog5\Catalog_Entries64
```

sample entries from first group, actual total in this group is about 45

[image]

Comment: Those are connected to a Group Policy Extension template you must have applied.  I see nothing malicious about those files.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. I suspect two DLNA server programs I installed a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the digital signature checking and VirusTotal checking in Autoruns.

`Menu Options / Scan options`

[image]

Then you will see something like

[image]

Almost all Microsoft DLL files are signed and signatures are verified (that means files were not modified by anybody). But for files without a signature you can see the VirusTotal rating. `0/x` means that a file was checked by `x` antivirus programs and `0` of them found that a file is suspicious.

Registry keys you have mentioned are created by Windows services.

For example, regarding the reg key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GpExtensions` see [The Basics of Group Policies](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/05/the-basics-of-group-policies.aspx).

Also, you can turn off unused services.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, you have been very helpful. I didn't know you could verify signatures and scan for viruses with Autoruns.